# "find: paths must precede expression:" error only when run in a script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, find

If I do my find command at the command line, it works fine, but if I try it in a script, I get this error. I run the command like

```
FILTER=" | grep -v \"test\""
files=`find . -type f -regex \".*$ext\" $FILTER`
```

if I do

```
echo "find . -type f -regex \".*$ext\" $FILTER"
```

it outputs

```
find . -type f -regex ".*.cpp" | grep -v "test"
```

which works fine at the command line. How can I get this to work in a script? I tried escaping the * too, but get the same error.

I've also noticed that

```
find . -type f -regex \".*$ext\"
```

gives no output when run in my shell script and I'm not sure why, because just like above, if I run that at command line, I get a list of .cpp files.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) And beware of `eval`, it's full of traps for the unwary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the shell reaches the ["expansions" stage](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Operation.html#Shell-Operation), control operators (such as `|`) have already been identified. The result of expansions is not parsed again in search of control structures.

When the command substitution in

```bsh
files=`find . -type f -regex \".*$ext\" $FILTER`
```

is expanded, Bash parses it as a simple command (`find`) followed by several arguments, two of them requiring expansion. You can turn tracing on to see the actual, expanded command:

```bsh
$ set -x
$ find . -type f -regex \".*$ext\" $FILTER
+ find . -type f -regex '".*cpp"' '|' grep -v '"test"'
```

If you compare it with

```bsh
$ set -x
$ find . -type f -regex ".*.cpp" | grep -v "test"
+ grep --color=auto -v test
+ find . -type f -regex '.*.cpp'
```

you can clearly see that, in the first case, the `|` is used as a one-character argument to `find`.

To dynamically build and execute a command string you need to explicitly add a new parsing stage. `eval` is a way to do that:

```bsh
$ set -x
$ files=$(eval "find . -type f -regex \".*$ext\" $FILTER")
++ eval 'find . -type f -regex ".*cpp"  | grep -v "test"'
+++ find . -type f -regex '.*cpp'
+++ grep --color=auto -v test
```

But note that, when executing a variable as a script, it is really important to make sure you have control on the variable's content for obvious security reasons. Since `eval` tends to also make programs harder to read and to debug, it is advisable to only use it as a last resort.

In your case, a better approach could be:

```bsh
filter=( -regex ".*$ext" '!' -name "*test*" )
find . -type f "${filter[@]}" -exec bash -c '
  # The part of your script that works with "files" goes here
  # "$@" holds a batch of file names
  ' mybash {} +
```

Which makes use of `find`'s flexibility and also correctly handles file names that include newline characters — a corner case that makes saving the output of `find` into a variable unreliable, in general, unless you use something like `mapfile -d '' files < <(find ... -print0)` (assuming Bash (since version 4.4) and a `find` implementation that supports the non-standard `-print0`). You can read more on this in [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/315749), also relevant in relation to piping `find`'s output.

Again, note that the `filter` array's elements can cause the execution of arbitrary code (think about `filter=( -exec something_evil ';' )`), so you still need to make sure you have control on its content.

Answer (score 5):

```
FILTER=" | grep -v \"test\""
```

Operators like `|` don't have their special meaning when they're the result of expansions. Same for quotes.

Make a function to hold the filter, the quoting is easier too:

```
filter() {
    grep -v "test"
}

files=$(find . -type f -regex ".*$ext" | filter)
```

Note that if you use `find` from command substitution like that, you're quashing the output to a single string, which will cause issues if you have filenames with whitespace.

---

If part of your reason to put the filter in a variable is to sometimes *not* have the filter, you can replace it with a null filter by redefining the function:

```
filter() {
    cat
}
```

or just making two functions, and then using a variable to decide which one to call:

```
filter() {
    grep -v "test"
}
filter_null() {
    cat
}
filter_used=filter
files=$(find . -type f -regex ".*$ext" | $filter_used)
```

Comment: I've seen questions on site with more about the problem of switching/removing commands from a pipeline at run-time, but for some reason, I can't _find_ any of them now.

Comment: You could even use `find ... | if [ "$filter" = null ]; then cat; else grep ...; fi`.  You might also want to say something about using `find` in a command substitution.